# Boot Linux Mint from SD-Card

Tags: linux, boot, graphics-card, linux-mint, sd-card

**The problem:**

I want a "moveable" Linux Mint image on a SD-Card. The SD-Card should have the linux installed and it should act as the storage of the system. I want to plug it in any PC and boot the OS from the SD-Card "plug and play"-like. It should act like the old Linux-testing-cd's.

So I have wondered if there is any way to achieve this. I have only found installation guides but no really useful tutorials to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a bootable drive with persistent storage. Check out this guide: https://www.fosslinux.com/60398/create-a-linux-mint-usb-drive-with-persistence.htm

Comment: Thank you man such people like you are gold nowadays! On stack-overflow are so many toxic people. The toxicity sucks. Thanks man! Have a great day!

Comment: Sure thing. And watch that physical write protection switch on the SD Card, those things get partially flipped accidentally and can lead to time wasted troubleshooting permissions.